# How to properly set width and height attributes of amp-img

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm currently in the process of making my website [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create.html)-ified my site is built in bootstrap and everything is responsive so most of my images I just set like so:

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

However the problem im running into with my `amp-img` is that it requires a `width` and `height` to be set on the image. What is the correct way of making responsive images with `amp` is there anyway to do this without setting `height` and `width`?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the width or height of your image the only way to show your image is to give it the l[ayout attribute fill](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout) and wrap it in a element with add which has the following [css property object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) set to contain.

```
.ampImg__Wrapper {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `amp` **requires the dimensions** to be in the  tag **for a reason**

**The size you put in there** is the size the `amp-script` uses to **generate a placeholder**. The placeholder **stops the content from jumping** around **while the images load**.

That being said, **just put the organic image dimensions** in the tag and **use the two following properties** in your `CSS` to make sure images play nice

(make sure you add a selector of-course)

```css
{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The AMP way to achieve that is by using the `layout` attribute. In amp-img, you specify the source, the **native** height and weight ; sourceset with formats, in "css pixels"(e.g. 96px/in) for your responsive image with `layout= responsive` and you're done. AMP will maintain the h/w ratio.

Ex.

```
<amp-img
    src="/img/small.jpg"
    srcset="/img/medium.jpg 640w,
           /img/small.jpg 320w"
    width="1800"
    height="2777"
    layout="responsive"
    alt="Don't forget to add one">
</amp-img>
```

In this example, the `layout="responsive"` would be inferred by the AMP engine because image size and formats are specified. When height and width are not defined, the default layout is "container" (e.g. like plain `div`).

You can also include amp media queries in amp-img. The preceding example could be set like this:

```
<amp-img
    media="(max-width: 639px)"
    src="/img/small.jpg"
    width="450"
    height="694"
    layout="responsive"
    alt="Don't forget to add one">
</amp-img>
<amp-img
    media="(min-width: 639px)"
    src="/img/medium.jpg"
    width="900"
    height="1388"
    layout="responsive"
    alt="Don't forget to add one">
</amp-img>
```

In this case, the "media" attribute will have precedence over the adaptative selection (but it makes almost no practical differences except if you want to force a certain image upon a certain screen size).

For a good overview: https://www.ampbyexample.com/advanced/layout_system/

Hope this help